# supress scientific notation when writing python floats to files

Tags: python, floating-point, notation

Writing floats to a CSV writes some of them like this: 2.0628800997782577e-05

```
c = csv.writer(open(file, "wb"))
c.writerow([var1, var2])
```

What I've tried:

- I have already tried var1**8 following other answers on
  StackOverflow, but this simply raises them to the power of 8.
- I have also tried Decimal(var1), but this does not suppress the scientific
  notation.

This makes it difficult to process the output in excel afterwards as it's recognized as text and not a number. How can I print it in non-scientific, decimal notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'%f' % your_var
```

Or to control the precision:

```
'%0.10f' % your_var
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
c.writerow(['{:f}'.format(var) for var in (var1, var2)]
```