# Python: Writing input data as it is to output file

Tags: python-2.7, type-conversion

So, i'm a total noob when it comes to programming, especially python. I'm trying to merge two files(based on my requirements) and store the result into an output file. I am easily being able to do the merge, but the issue i'm facing is with the data format. **You see, the data in the output file must be in the same format as the input file**

These are my input files:

File1:

```
ID,CLASS,BOARD_ID
3620694,Smart,233049933699
3620724,Smart,233200309044
3620819,Smart,233200971094
3620831,Smart,233201075614
3620865,Smart,233201516374
3620870,Smart,233201553354
3620906,Smart,233201863244
3620929,Smart,233201972254
3620963,Smart,233202244014
3621008,Smart,233202600234
3621107,Smart,233203534474
3621158,Smart,233204019454
3621179,Smart,233204093854
3621252,Smart,233204801364
3621254,Smart,233204815324
3621266,Smart,233205000144
3621275,Smart,233205104774
3621288,Smart,233205182584
```

File2:

```
CDUS,CBSCS,CTRS,CTRS_ID
0,0,0.000000000375,233010056572
0,0,4.0746,233200309044
0,0,0.6182,233200971094
0,0,15.4834,233201075614
0,0,2.2459,233201516374
0,0,0.148,233201553354
0,0,0.0468,233201863244
0,0,0.5045,233201972254
0,0,0.0000000000485,233049933699
```

So this is my python script:

```
 import pandas
 #pandas.set_option('display.precision',13)
 csv1 = pandas.read_csv('OUTPUT_1707000867_BundleCrossCellData_45432477_0_0.txt',dtype={'BOARD_ID': str})
 csv2 = pandas.read_csv('I2.txt',dtype={'CTRS_ID': str}).rename(columns={'CTRS_ID':'BOARD_ID'})
 merged = pandas.merge(csv1, csv2,left_on=['BOARD_ID'],right_on=['BOARD_ID'],how='left',suffixes=('#x', '#y'), sort=True)
 merged.to_csv("Op2.txt", index=False,date_format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.000',float_format='%.13f')
```

Output received upon execution:

Op.txt

`ID,CLASS,BOARD_ID,CDUS,CBSCS,CTRS
3620694,Smart,233049933699,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000485
3620724,Smart,233200309044,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,4.0746000000000
3620819,Smart,233200971094,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.6182000000000
3620831,Smart,233201075614,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,15.4834000000000
3620865,Smart,233201516374,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,2.2459000000000
3620870,Smart,233201553354,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.1480000000000
3620906,Smart,233201863244,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0468000000000
3620929,Smart,233201972254,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.5045000000000
3620963,Smart,233202244014,,,
3621008,Smart,233202600234,,,
3621107,Smart,233203534474,,,
3621158,Smart,233204019454,,,
3621179,Smart,233204093854,,,
3621252,Smart,233204801364,,,
3621254,Smart,233204815324,,,
3621266,Smart,233205000144,,,
3621275,Smart,233205104774,,,
3621288,Smart,233205182584,,,`

Expected Output:

`ID,CLASS,BOARD_ID,CDUS,CBSCS,CTRS
3620694,Smart,233049933699,0,0,0.0000000000485
3620724,Smart,233200309044,0,0,4.0746000000000
3620819,Smart,233200971094,0,0,0.6182000000000
3620831,Smart,233201075614,0,0,15.4834000000000
3620865,Smart,233201516374,0,0,2.2459000000000
3620870,Smart,233201553354,0,0,0.1480000000000
3620906,Smart,233201863244,0,0,0.0468000000000
3620929,Smart,233201972254,0,0,0.5045000000000
3620963,Smart,233202244014,,,
3621008,Smart,233202600234,,,
3621107,Smart,233203534474,,,
3621158,Smart,233204019454,,,
3621179,Smart,233204093854,,,
3621252,Smart,233204801364,,,
3621254,Smart,233204815324,,,
3621266,Smart,233205000144,,,
3621275,Smart,233205104774,,,
3621288,Smart,233205182584,,,`

**As you can see in Op.txt, values of CDUS and CBSCS are not in the same format as in File2.txt. For obvious reasons both have to be in same format.**

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Also since the input files are being generated at runtime, i cannot statically type-cast a certain column to a certain type.

I also referenced following links, but didnt find an appropriate solution. Any help would be very much appreciated.

[How do I suppress scientific notation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python)
[Force python to not output a float in standard form / scientific notation / exponential form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345795/force-python-to-not-output-a-float-in-standard-form-scientific-notation-expo)
[Casting float to string without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665523/casting-float-to-string-without-scientific-notation)
[supress scientific notation when writing python floats to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605235/supress-scientific-notation-when-writing-python-floats-to-files)
[Suppressing scientific notation in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas)

Comment: Guys any ideas? Kindly take some time to explain to me what i'm doing wrong here.